# How to get hits.second in BigQuery?

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I'm newb on BigQuery. Is-it possible to get hit.second in a way in BigQuery?
My idea would be after to concat hits_time, hits_hour, hits_minute with date to display in a column the date with time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  visitId,
  hit.hitNumber,
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) AS visitStart, 
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1000 * visitStartTime + hit.time) AS hitStart
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`, UNNEST(hits) AS hit
ORDER BY 1, 2
LIMIT 100
```

From [BigQuery Export Schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719):

```sql
hits.time   INTEGER The number of milliseconds after the visitStartTime when this  
                    hit was registered. The first hit has a hits.time of 0
```

Comment: Thanks @mikhail-berlyant for your answer

Comment: May I ask you why the following query is not working on BQ please?

Comment: 1st part of the query
SELECT
DATE,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN customDimensions.index = 1 THEN customDimensions.value END) AS CUSTOMDIMENSIONS_VALUE,  visitNumber,  fullvisitorid,   device.deviceCategory,  hits.page.pagePath,  IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel2, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,  IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel3, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3,  hits.page.pageTitle,  
 TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) AS visitStart, 
 TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1000 * visitStartTime + hits.time) AS hitStart

Comment: 2nd part of the query:  hits.hitNumber,
  hits.hour,
  hits.minute,
  hits.isEntrance,
  hits.isExit,
  CONCAT(fullvisitorid, STRING(visitid)) AS sessionid
FROM (FLATTEN([Table], customDimensions.value ))
WHERE
  hits.page.hostname CONTAINS 'X''
  AND customDimensions.value != "null"
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
  AND (customDimensions.index = 1 OR hits.customDimensions.index = 11) GROUP EACH BY
DATE,
  visitStartTime,
  fullVisitorId,
  visitNumber,
  device.deviceCategory,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  hits.page.pageTitle,
  hits.hitNumber,
  hits.time,
  hits.hour,

Comment: 3rd part of the query: hits.minute,
  hits.isEntrance,
  hits.isExit
LIMIT
  100000

Comment: btw. on SO - if you want to ask next question  - just post new one and we will be more than happy to help you with it. Using comments to asking new questions - is not productive at all as it is hard to read it and no way to answer without ruining already existing question. So, my recommendation - just go and post new question :o)